# Spring rest validation of a custom class

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I have a RestController method that takes a json string input (converted to a Search class):

```
results(@NotNull @Valid String id, @Valid Search search) {}
```

How can I add validation of the contents of this class? If there is a mistake in the json input I will not be able to know it as the fields will just be empty. I want to return a response to the client if there is a mistake.

F.ex. there is a field called 'select'. If there is a typo and they put 'seletc' in the json, the select field in the class will just be null and no error is found. So I want to do some validation of the json parameter BEFORE spring converts the json to a class. What is the best approach to do this?

The Search class looks like this:

```
public class Search {

@Valid
private List<String> select = new ArrayList<>();

@Valid
private List<@Valid Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();


public Search(List<String> select, List<@Valid Filter> filters) {
  this.select = select;
  this.filters = filters;
}
```

Comment: You're already using `@Valid`. The same validation library offers annotations to define *what* needs to be validated. You can find which ones and how to use them in the same article that told you to use `@Valid` (and many thousands more).

Comment: Yes, you are correct that I'm already using some validation. But as stated in the original post, I need to do some validation on the json before it is converted into a class. No validation library can do that for me (as I'm aware of).

Comment: Seems more like a Front end validation problem.

Comment: @hermit Front end only validation is never enough. Because you shouldn't assume that your front end is the only user of your backend, even if the API isn't documented.

Answer (score 0):

By what I see here you are using a lot of @Valid that you propably don't need.
@Valid annotation lets you 'run' validator on objects and check if they met validation criteria made by you using annotations. So in you case this will propably solve your issue.

```
public class Search {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Message for user")
    private List<String> select = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotEmpty(message = "Message for user")
    private List</* Use @Valid here if Filter class has some validation */Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();


    public Search(List<String> select, List<Filter> filters) {
        this.select = select;
        this.filters = filters;
    }
}
```

And your contoller:

```
test(@NotNull String id, @Valid Search search) {}
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer. I am using some contraints in some of the underlying classes, that is why the @Valid's are there. Some may be unnecessary tho.

However this will not solve my issue as f.ex. the 'select' field can be empty. That is why I need to add some validation of the json input BEFORE it is converted to the class as the conversion can emit some data if there is an error in the json.

Comment: By the example and the explanation I don't think I understand correctly, but when you use `@NotEmpty` for a collection it checks for two things, first if it is null and if the size is greater than zero. If a validation fails, you still need a class that is a `@ControllerAdvice` together with `@ExceptionHandler` method to catch `MethodArgumentNotValidException`,
then you need to extract error messages and present them in a "nice way" for user by returning them in a ResponseEntity for example.